# JSON Parsing error when serializing a PUT request

Tags: apex, apexrest

I have created the following Apex class. This is a web service that basically takes a list of JSON response in the following format:

```
[
    {"ticketName" : "INC0611231", "Status" : "Closed", "workNotes" : "Bigfoot 3Sighting!"},
    {"ticketName" : "INC0611230","Status" : "Closed","workNotes" : "Bigfoot 3Sighting!"},
    {"ticketName" : "INC0611229","Status" : "Closed","workNotes" : "Bigfoot 3Sighting!"}
]
```

and then updates the Salesforce record. When I am using Workbench to test my web service and pasting the JSON in the body, I keep on getting an error in Workbench saying the JSON request body must be an object at [line 1, column2];

I have my APEX below:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/tickets/*')
global class CC_WebService {
    @HttpPut
    global static List<Ticket__c> updateServiceTicket(String jsonString){
        List<TicketStatus> snow = (List<TicketStatus>)JSON.deserialize(jsonString, List<TicketStatus>.class); 
        System.debug('*****This is the JSON serialized*****' + snow);
        Map<String, TicketStatus> MapticketNumber = new Map<String, TicketStatus>();
        
        List<Ticket__c> ticketstoUpdate = new List<Ticket__c>();
        
        for(TicketStatus ss : snow){
            MapticketNumber.put(ss.ticketName, ss);
        }
        
        List<Ticket__c> st = [SELECT Name, Status__c, Comments_and_Work_Notes__c FROM Ticket__c WHERE Name IN: MapticketNumber.keySet()];

        for(Service_Ticket__c s : st){
            s.Status__c = MapticketNumber.get(s.Name).Status;
            s.Comments_and_Work_Notes__c = MapticketNumber.get(s.Name).workNotes;
            ticketstoUpdate.add(s);
        }
        
        try{
            update ticketstoUpdate;  
        }
        catch(DMLException e) {
            system.debug('***************************************** ' + e.getMessage()); 
            system.debug('***************************************** ' + e.getStackTraceString());
        } 
 
        return ticketstoUpdate;
        
    }
public class TicketStatus {
        public String ticketName;
        public String Status;
        public String workNotes;
    } 
}
```

Can someone please help me? Do I need to change the serialization code? I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use String as the parameter and manually deserialize in apex. The platform can automatically deserialize it for you if your parameter names and the JSON have the same name.

Modify your code as below

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/tickets/*')

global class CC_WebService {
 @HttpPut
 global static List<Ticket__c> updateServiceTicket(List<TicketStatus> lstticketstatus){
            
 Map<String, TicketStatus> MapticketNumber = new Map<String, TicketStatus>();
    
    List<Ticket__c> ticketstoUpdate = new List<Ticket__c>();
    
    for(TicketStatus ss : lstticketstatus){
        MapticketNumber.put(ss.ticketName, ss);
    }
    
    List<Ticket__c> st = [SELECT Name, Status__c, Comments_and_Work_Notes__c FROM Ticket__c WHERE Name IN: MapticketNumber.keySet()];

    for(Service_Ticket__c s : st){
        s.Status__c = MapticketNumber.get(s.Name).Status;
        s.Comments_and_Work_Notes__c = MapticketNumber.get(s.Name).workNotes;
        ticketstoUpdate.add(s);
    }
    
    try{
        update ticketstoUpdate;  
    }
    catch(DMLException e) {
        system.debug('***************************************** ' + e.getMessage()); 
        system.debug('***************************************** ' + e.getStackTraceString());
    } 
    return ticketstoUpdate;
}

global class TicketStatus {
    public String ticketName;
    public String Status;
    public String workNotes;
  } 

}
```

And note that request should use same string as method parameter

```
{"lstticketstatus" : [{
        "ticketName": "INC0611231",
        "Status": "Closed",
        "workNotes": "Bigfoot 3Sighting!"
    },
    {
        "ticketName": "INC0611230",
        "Status": "Closed",
        "workNotes": "Bigfoot 3Sighting!"
    },
    {
        "ticketName": "INC0611229",
        "Status": "Closed",
        "workNotes": "Bigfoot 3Sighting!"
    }
]}
```

If you want to get rid of the Object and just use String body here is how you will do it

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/tickets/*')

global class CC_WebService {
@HttpPut
 global static List<Ticket__c> updateServiceTicket(){

   RestRequest request = RestContext.request; 
   String jsonString = request.requestBody.toString(); 

   List<TicketStatus> snow = (List<TicketStatus>)JSON.deserialize(jsonString, List<TicketStatus>.class); 


   Map<String, TicketStatus> MapticketNumber = new Map<String, TicketStatus>();

   List<Ticket__c> ticketstoUpdate = new List<Ticket__c>();

   for(TicketStatus ss : lstticketstatus){
     MapticketNumber.put(ss.ticketName, ss);
   }

    List<Ticket__c> st = [SELECT Name, Status__c, Comments_and_Work_Notes__c FROM Ticket__c WHERE Name IN: MapticketNumber.keySet()];

 for(Service_Ticket__c s : st){
    s.Status__c = MapticketNumber.get(s.Name).Status;
    s.Comments_and_Work_Notes__c = 
     MapticketNumber.get(s.Name).workNotes;
    ticketstoUpdate.add(s);
  }

 try{
     update ticketstoUpdate;  
 }
 catch(DMLException e) {
    system.debug('***************************************** ' + e.getMessage()); 
    system.debug('***************************************** ' + e.getStackTraceString());
   } 
    return ticketstoUpdate;
  }

  global class TicketStatus {
    public String ticketName;
    public String Status;
    public String workNotes;
  } 

}
```

Now for this, the request JSON will be as

```
[{
    "ticketName": "INC0611231",
    "Status": "Closed",
    "workNotes": "Bigfoot 3Sighting!"
},
{
    "ticketName": "INC0611230",
    "Status": "Closed",
    "workNotes": "Bigfoot 3Sighting!"
},
 {
    "ticketName": "INC0611229",
    "Status": "Closed",
    "workNotes": "Bigfoot 3Sighting!"
  }
]
```

Comment: In your code I feel like you are assuming that the person making the request has to parse the json and send it. I think the people requesting will send a json string which we will have to parse. I a also a bit unsure what you are doing. How did you skip so many lines and go straiht to the query? Are you implying I keep what I had above it?

Comment: Yes keep the code you have. But make sure you use parameters correctly. Why are you using strings and deserializing it

Comment: I just updated with your code. Try it

Comment: Thank you! @Mohith Shrivastava! So does that mean that the other person can not send the request as a json? It will have to in this specific format? Or they can send json so long as it has ticketname, status, worknotes? Thanks again

Comment: Its a JSON. We need to wrap the array within an Object. Its JSON object than sending as an array.

Comment: @user3688231 I have also added another version that should let you pass a JSON array straight up

Comment: thank you so much! Thats wonderful!

Answer (score 0):

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/tickets/*') global class CC_WebService { @HttpPut global static List<Ticket__c> updateServiceTicket(){RestRequest req=RestContext.request; RestResponse res = Restcontext.response;String reqJson = req.requestBody.toString();system.debug('req--'+req.requestBody.toString()); } 
                                                                           try enclosing that JSON in curly braces which represent object
```

{"Tickets" :
[
{"ticketName" : "INC0611231", "Status" : "Closed", "workNotes" : "Bigfoot 3Sighting!"},
{"ticketName" : "INC0611230","Status" : "Closed","workNotes" : "Bigfoot 3Sighting!"},
{"ticketName" : "INC0611229","Status" : "Closed","workNotes" : "Bigfoot 3Sighting!"}
]
}

Comment: I am still getting JSON Parse error however it now says "Unexpected parameter encounteed during deseriialization: Tickets at line comun 16]

Comment: In rest resource class request you have to access like this RestRequest req=RestContext.request;
RestResponse res = Restcontext.response;String reqJson = req.requestBody.toString();
        system.debug('req--'+req.requestBody.toString()); and use the JSON {"Tickets" : [ {"ticketName" : "INC0611231", "Status" : "Closed", "workNotes" : "Bigfoot 3Sighting!"}, {"ticketName" : "INC0611230","Status" : "Closed","workNotes" : "Bigfoot 3Sighting!"}, {"ticketName" : "INC0611229","Status" : "Closed","workNotes" : "Bigfoot 3Sighting!"} ] }

Comment: Hello @Ashwini Dengi, can you modify the code above that I put in the question?. I am a little confused on where to write that

Comment: Using string and deserializing will mean more CPU time consumed and an overhead.

Comment: @RestResource(urlMapping='/tickets/*')

global class CC_WebService {
 @HttpPut
 global static List<Ticket__c> updateServiceTicket(){RestRequest req=RestContext.request; RestResponse res = Restcontext.response;String reqJson = req.requestBody.toString();system.debug('req--'+req.requestBody.toString());
 }

Comment: @AshwiniDengi That looks good!!

Comment: @AshwiniDengi Please post that as an answer and use the format button to format the code.